# SimpleAudioEngine fails to play SFX after soft reset but not every time

Tags: audio, simpleaudioengine

When handling soft resets in iOS anyone have any idea why resumeAllEffects() may not work? Have tried calling within Appdelegate and in our Main.js (we're doing a load under JS)...

Only thing that seems to fix it is restarting the engine under AudioEngine.end

```
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground(){

if (applicationHasBeenToBackground)
{
    applicationHasBeenToBackground = false;

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(AppDelegate::delayedOnWillEnterForeground), this, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, false);
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeAllEffects();
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
            cout << "\n\n\n RESUME \n\n\n";


}}
```

The more detailed part is - if the **resumeBackgroundMusic** part is included and I single tap home, then the effects stop. If I remove the resumeBackgroundMusic the effects behave correctly, as does the music.... but then the music will not mute on double tap....

When doing the same from another part of the game - (a whole front end menu area) - then the opposite happens.

any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried? Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on providing a minimal but complete example of your code.

Comment: Calls in various Appdelegate parts; 
for example void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() etc.... all the usual stuff. The problem is when calling resumeAllEffects effects are not resumed.